# How to loop through cells in a sheet to search another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to search "Check" Sheet for values from "Text" sheet.

How can I create a loop for "Text" sheet from cell value A2 to A4 one by one.

I have created below code

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer
Dim WS, W As Range

Sub Search_fn()

Set WS = Range("B2")

WS = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(Sheet2.Range("A2"), Range("A2"), 1)

End Sub
```

This shows 1004 error and I am also not able to crate the loop for all values.

Sheet "Check"
[image]

Sheet "text"
[image]